# How to add gcc libraries and cross compile for windows?

Tags: c, linux, windows, gcc, cross-compiling

When I use minGW for cross compiling for windows I get these errors. How can I add gcc library and cross compile for windows?
I am using x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
But it compiles with gcc without any issues.
The issue arises from having different search.h in gcc and in minGW
It hard to show minimum reproducible results here.
You can find the source code and the cmake file the following link
< https://gitlab.com/DirtyVoid/computer_systems/-/tree/main/Assignment4%20MorseCodeDecoder >
If I change the compiler to gcc instead of mingw everything works
I am on GNU LINUX but when I try to compile an exe using minGW it does not work
The compiler error is due the fact search.h in gcc and mingw has different definitions.

```
./CMake clean-install
-- Cleaning files and directories
-- Deleting program: MorseCodeDecoder - done
-- Deleting build directory: build/ - done
-- Cleaning - done
-- Creating a new empty build directory:/home/dirtyv/Codes/computer_systems/Assignment4 MorseCodeDecoder/build/ - done
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc - works
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/dirtyv/Codes/computer_systems/Assignment4 MorseCodeDecoder/build
[ 20%] Building C object CMakeFiles/MORSE_LIB.dir/src/morse_lib/morse_code.c.o
In file included from /home/dirtyv/Codes/computer_systems/Assignment4 MorseCodeDecoder/inc/main.h:29,
                 from /home/dirtyv/Codes/computer_systems/Assignment4 MorseCodeDecoder/src/morse_lib/morse_code.c:1:
/home/dirtyv/Codes/computer_systems/Assignment4 MorseCodeDecoder/inc/read.h:10:62: warning: 'struct hsearch_data' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
   10 | extern void read_morse_display_word(FILE *morse_file, struct hsearch_data *);
      |                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/dirtyv/Codes/computer_systems/Assignment4 MorseCodeDecoder/src/morse_lib/morse_code.c: In function 'load_morse_code_into_hashtable':
/home/dirtyv/Codes/computer_systems/Assignment4 MorseCodeDecoder/src/morse_lib/morse_code.c:37:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'hcreate_r' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   37 |         hcreate_r(capacity, hashtable);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~
/home/dirtyv/Codes/computer_systems/Assignment4 MorseCodeDecoder/src/morse_lib/morse_code.c:43:32: warning: implicit declaration of function 'hsearch_r'; did you mean 'bsearch_s'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   43 |                 int hsrc_res = hsearch_r(item, ENTER, &item_ptr, hashtable);
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~
      |                                bsearch_s
/home/dirtyv/Codes/computer_systems/Assignment4 MorseCodeDecoder/src/morse_lib/morse_code.c: In function 'clear_hashtable':
/home/dirtyv/Codes/computer_systems/Assignment4 MorseCodeDecoder/src/morse_lib/morse_code.c:51:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'hdestroy_r' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   51 |         hdestroy_r(hashtable);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~
[ 40%] Building C object CMakeFiles/MORSE_LIB.dir/src/morse_lib/read.c.o
In file included from /home/dirtyv/Codes/computer_systems/Assignment4 MorseCodeDecoder/inc/main.h:29,
                 from /home/dirtyv/Codes/computer_systems/Assignment4 MorseCodeDecoder/src/morse_lib/read.c:1:
/home/dirtyv/Codes/computer_systems/Assignment4 MorseCodeDecoder/inc/read.h:10:62: warning: 'struct hsearch_data' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
   10 | extern void read_morse_display_word(FILE *morse_file, struct hsearch_data *);
      |                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/dirtyv/Codes/computer_systems/Assignment4 MorseCodeDecoder/src/morse_lib/read.c:24:6: error: conflicting types for 'read_morse_display_word'; have 'void(FILE *, struct hsearch_data *)' {aka 'void(struct _iobuf *, struct hsearch_data *)'}
   24 | void read_morse_display_word(FILE *morse_file, struct hsearch_data *hashtable) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/dirtyv/Codes/computer_systems/Assignment4 MorseCodeDecoder/inc/main.h:29,
                 from /home/dirtyv/Codes/computer_systems/Assignment4 MorseCodeDecoder/src/morse_lib/read.c:1:
/home/dirtyv/Codes/computer_systems/Assignment4 MorseCodeDecoder/inc/read.h:10:13: note: previous declaration of 'read_morse_display_word' with type 'void(FILE *, struct hsearch_data *)' {aka 'void(struct _iobuf *, struct hsearch_data *)'}
   10 | extern void read_morse_display_word(FILE *morse_file, struct hsearch_data *);
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/MORSE_LIB.dir/build.make:90: CMakeFiles/MORSE_LIB.dir/src/morse_lib/read.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/MORSE_LIB.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] of the failing code, and [edit] your question to show it to us.

Comment: Hi I added the source code link using gitlab it is not possible to add the entire code as it will take the attention away from the actual problem but you can use the git lab link to reproduce it when you are on gnu linux using MinGW compiler instead of GCC

Comment: Try forward-declaring the struct before using it as a function parameter type.

Comment: I thought of that but the issue is do I have to re implement `hsearch_r(item, ACTION, &item_ptr, hashtable)` function? that is also not found.

Comment: Where is this `struct hsearch_data` type defined? In which header file? Do you remember to `#include` that header file?

Comment: It is defined in <search.h> for gcc but apparently not defined for minGW.
I have the headers file included. Only thing i changed is the name of the compiler in my cmake. Everything else is the same

Comment: Please don't rely on external links for showing code. Those links may become invalid, disappear, or the code may change unexpectedly. If any of that happens your question becomes totally worthless. Remember, this site isn't here to only you with this problem at this point in time, they should also be able to help future users.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I understand that I do not think I will take those links down unless gitlab goes away. Also, it is only reproducible in the true sense if I share the entire source code.

Comment: A simple example reproducing your problem would be e.g. `#include <search.h> /* Newline here */ int main(void) { struct hsearch_data htab; hcreate_r(51, &htab); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hcreate_r` and the `hsearch_data` structure are GNU-specific extensions to [the standard POSIX search functions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/hcreate.html).

According to [the Linux manuap page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/hsearch.3.html) you must define `_GNU_SOURCE` before including `<search.h>` to get that functionality.

As an extension of the standard it might not be available for MinGW though.

Comment: Is there any way to add them through a static library or something?

Comment: I have the same problem with getline